# Common case in switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I need to execute the common case and then the specific case, so this is what I'm doing:

```
let array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

array.forEach(element => {
    switch (element) {
        case 'baz':
            console.log('its baz');
            break;
        case 'foo':
        case 'bar':
            console.log('its foo or bar');
        case 'foo':
            console.log('its foo');
            break;
        case 'bar':
            console.log('its bar');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Outputs:

```
its foo or bar
its foo
its foo or bar
its foo // expected: 'its bar'
its baz
```

It works fine for `foo` but not `bar`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch-case works in this fashion: The control is transferred from the switch statement to the first match and then all the statements are executed(including those from other cases) until a break statement is encountered. This behavior is known as fallthrough.

So, Whenever this case is caught in switch,

```
case 'foo':
case 'bar':
    console.log('its foo or bar');
```

This case is always called:

```
 case 'foo':
    console.log('its foo');
```

The reason is that there is no break statement after the first snippet. So, the control goes on executing the statements until it encounters a break statement.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the situation that you're facing is already being explained by @SHRAIYSH. Below is another solution which you might be looking for

```js
let array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

array.forEach(element => {
    switch (element) {
        case 'baz':
            console.log('its baz');
            break;
        case 'foo':
        case 'bar':
            console.log('its foo or bar');
            if(element==='foo'){
             console.log('its inner foo');
            }else{
              console.log('its inner bar')
            }
        break;
        case 'foo':
            console.log('its foo');
            break;
        case 'bar':
            console.log('its bar');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

When dealing with `switch` statement, it can only fulfill one case. So instead of using sideEffect which satisfy only foo, you can use another `if else` within the case

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2 nested `switch` statement as follows:

```
let array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

array.forEach(element => {
    switch (element) {
        case 'baz':
            console.log('its baz');
            break;
        case 'foo':
        case 'bar':
             console.log('its foo or bar');
             switch (element) {
                 case 'foo':
                    console.log('its foo');
                    break;
                 case 'bar':
                    console.log('its bar');
                    break;
             }
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
let array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

array.forEach(element => {
    switch (element) {
        case 'baz':
            console.log('its baz');
            break;
        case 'foo':
        case 'bar':
            console.log('its foo or bar');
        case 'foo':
            if (element === 'foo')  {
                console.log('its foo');
                break;
            }
        case 'bar':
            console.log('its bar');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is highly not recommended, it hurts reader's eyes and imagine when the case grows bigger and bigger, it surely comes back and bite you and by that time i dont think you can easily refactor the code